# Ember evented on error: Assertion Failed: on called without valid event names

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dom-events, ember.js-2

I have a controller in my ember 2.18 app and I want to make it listen to some event `myEventName` triggered somewhere in the app, to change the model properties.

According to [the API docs for this version](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.18/classes/Evented/methods/on?anchor=on) the way to catch an emitted event is like this:

```
import Evented from '@ember/object/evented';
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
// extend some object, like a Controller
const myExtendedObject = Controller.extend(Evented, { 
    // stuff ...
     });

myExtendedObject.on('myEventName', function (args) {  
    console.log("catch importDone  ok", args); 
    });
export default myExtendedObject;
```

the code compiles well with ember build dev,
but in the browser's JS console I get this error message:

> Error: Assertion Failed: on called without valid event names error.js:40

I tried renaming event, but I cannot find why the event name is wrong.
I also tried to set three arguments to the `on` method, but it is still bugging with the event name.
What am I missing?

Edit:
I made an Ember twiddle showing that events are scoped to components.
I would like to catch them from anywhere;
like triggering an event from a Service and catch it in a Route.

https://ember-twiddle.com/ce22cc0a542e8e0997a1ad57a4a9688c?fullScreen=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
import { on } from '@ember/object/evented';

export default Controller.extend(Evented, {
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.trigger('greet');
  },

  myGreetImplementation: on('greet', function() {
    console.log('hello');
  })
});
```

Another example: Using a service to manage the user settings and subscribing to changes:

```
export default Service.extend(Evented, {
  ...
  changeProfilePicture() {
    ...
    this.trigger('profilePictureChanged', ... event parameters ...);
  }
});
```

Then you could watch for such event anywhere using the `on` method:

```
 export default Controller.extend({
  userSettings: service(),

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.get('userSettings').on('profilePictureChanged', this, this.profilePictureChanged);
  },

  profilePictureChanged(... event parameters ...) {
   ...
  }
});
```

There error you get is coming from here:
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/6fc89cdf13124d88b8ae6adf99bb02a8c0cdf508/packages/ember-metal/lib/events.ts#L211
(You can just paste error messages in the github search or use the debugger to find out more about why something is failing)

---

Update: Extending your twiddle to have the Controller register on the service's event:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { on } from '@ember/object/evented';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
  myService: service(),
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.get('myService').on('mycall', this, this.mycallHandler);
  },
  mycallHandler: on('mycall', function() {
    console.log('here we are');
  })
});
```

Comment: thank for the examples. but i dont find a way to make the emitted events to be catched outside their own service/component/controller. which makes it not very useful.  in my case i have a TransferService which triggers and event "timeToReloadFile" when a user has succefully uploaded some files. but the documentListController, which listens on that event never catches it. no idea why.

Comment: Yeah, the events are tied to an Ember.Object (Component, Controller, Service etc.). So if you need something like a global event bus, you could have a service called like that and trigger and register events there...

You might want to checkout:
https://github.com/blia/ember-cli-events-bus/

All that's necessary:
https://github.com/blia/ember-cli-events-bus/blob/master/addon/services/events-bus.js

The other file https://github.com/blia/ember-cli-events-bus/blob/master/addon/initializers/events-bus.js is just taking care that you don't have to register this service every time.